# Grails 3 - springSecurity reauthenticate with password

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, grails3

I've just happened to notice that using

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(userid, password)
```

for manual user authentication (in a controller) succeeds regardless of the value for `password`, i.e. correct password, wrong password, null password, etc.

Am I missing something?
The declaration of springSecurityService's method is
`void reauthenticate(String username, String password = null)`
so at first I was pretty confident that a password check was in place.

*Config*

- Grails 3.2.4
- Spring Security Plugin (core) 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reauthenticate` method updates the current Security context with UserDetails instance found by the email you provide to the `reauthenticate` method. It does not perform any validation as it is an internal call. It also removes the user from the user cache to force a refresh at next login.

So if you do not pass the password parameter, it is going to use the password from the UserDetails instance and set the authentication context with these details.

Have a look at the code [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils.groovy#L512)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, thanks! Apparently I misunderstood the purpose of the `password` parameter.
For who's interested, I used `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder.matches()` to validate the password separately.